# RVM requirements error

Tags: ruby, rvm, osx-mavericks

I have OS X Mavericks installed and I'm trying to run `rvm requirements` in terminal and it gives me this error.

`Installing required packages: autoconf, automake, libtool, pkgconfig, libyaml, libffi, readline, libksba, curl-ca-bundle, gdbm.............
Error running 'requirements_osx_port_libs_install autoconf automake libtool pkgconfig libyaml libffi readline libksba curl-ca-bundle gdbm',
please read /Users/Alex/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.3-p448/1374263757_package_install_autoconf_automake_libtool_pkgconfig_libyaml_libffi_readline_libksba_curl-ca-bundle_gdbm.log
Requirements installation failed with status: 1.`

Comment: Could you post the contents of the log file in the traceback?

Comment: here https://gist.github.com/alexclp/36167ac4189d0d8764d5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like RVM tried to install some dependencies using Macports and Macports proceeded to get really confused about dependencies when it tried to install autoconf.

Try running:

```
brew install autoconf
```

Otherwise you should run this bash script:

https://gist.github.com/siraj/1399288

Assuming you have brew, which you should if you don't.

If your Macports just isn't working, then you can manually install all of the requirements like this:

```
brew install autoconf automake libtool pkgconfig libyaml libffi readline libksba curl-ca-bundle gdbm
```

Comment: I tried to run `brew install m4 perl15 perl15.12 gdbm xz`, but it gave me this error: `Error: No available formula for m4 `

Comment: @alexclp did you try brew install autoconf first?

Comment: If that was successful you should just try to go ahead with the rvm requirements install. That's what it failed on before.

Comment: Installed all requirements, tried to run that bash script and failed :( also, it gives me the same error as before when I'm trying to run `rvm requirements`

Comment: @alexclp if it failed again could you post the log file again? I'm willing to bet it just failed down the line. Basically your Macports is busted and you need to install all the rvm dependencies with brew instead.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the above, and a few other things. None worked.

It seems that on OSX 10.9 and XCode5 moved some libs around on us. So I had to install XCode5-DP6 (Dev Preview 6), opened up DP6 and in the settings, you have to tell the command line tools to use the new DP6 build and not the Standard XCode from the marketplace.

First, I had to install homebrew. Nothing liked to play with macports. I am on my first mac as of only a month ago, so macports was just what solved apache for me at the time. I then had to run 'brew install autoconf'

Once I did that I then ran `rvm requirements`, everything installed without issue. then `sudo gem install jekyll` from there and it all works like a charm now.

I'm sure once Mavericks is actually released this will get ironed out. We are using early releases after all...

Hope this works for you guys.